# Highcharts - Pinch zoom does not work on chart with multiple y axes

Tags: highcharts

I'm having two charts that share the same x axis.
I'd like to be able to pinch zoom both x and y in the top chart. Is this possible?

I can't get it to work in this example where I'm setting pinchType: 'xy'.
https://jsfiddle.net/oloflandahl/xrh8135c/6/

```
chart: {
  pinchType: 'xy'
}
```

pinchType: 'x' works fine when having two charts/y-axes

pinchType: 'xy' works fine when having only one chart/y-axis

pinchType: 'xy' does not work when having two charts/y-axes

Answer (score 0):

By default, the **pinchType** is inherited from the value set in the **zoomType** and it seems that while using **zoomType** feature, everything works as it should be - tested also on the mobile device.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g9repty0

```
chart: {
    zoomType: 'xy'
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.pinchType

Please test it and let me know what you think.

---

EDIT

My mistake. The vertical pinch doesn't work for the multiple pane. I reported it as a bug on Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13217

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear in my description. I want pinch zoom to be working on touch devices. I'll change my description.

Comment: Have you tested the demo which I shared? Here is a link which you can display straight on your mobile device - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g9repty0/show

Comment: I tried the demo. Only the x axis is zoomed on mobile.

Comment: That's strange - on iOS works fine - both - y & x axis are zoomed. On what device have you test it?